# How to forbid auto deleting a docker container after exit

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was using wsl2 Ubuntu 20.04 with docker. I created a container in wsl, but when I exit from the container, the docker automatically deleted the container. Yet I didn't have this problem when I created a container from windows command line.

How to prevent docker from auto deleting the container I created in wsl command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you may have created the container with `docker run [...] --rm [...]`.  This will cause the container to be removed when the container exits.  To prevent auto-removal, be sure not to include `--rm` when creating your container